# Chrome scrollbar is broken when using flex layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to customise the chrome scrollbar on a div that is set to display: flex, the scrollbars are broken (see screenshot: The screenshot shows double up and down arrows, and the horizontal scrollbar is missing the dragging part).

It looks fine without setting the div (.container) to be display: flex, but my system is full of flex layout.

Can anyone help to solve the problem? Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
            background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAABlBMVEXM09b///8OmaLeAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAiSURBVHgBY2BEAxQJMKAJMKAJMKAJMOATgIkQMBTBooZfAH56AO2yINTrAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
            background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAABlBMVEXM09b///8OmaLeAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAgSURBVHgBY2BEA+QLMGAIMGAIMGAIMBAUIGQoZU5HAwB+ZgDtGYq3fgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
            background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAABlBMVEXM09b///8OmaLeAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAfSURBVHgBY2BEA7QTYIAChAoYH6EFxkeYwQBj0MelAH3GAO2C9+AaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
            background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAABlBMVEXM09b///8OmaLeAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAgSURBVHgBY2BEAzQVYIAzYHwGGAvOZ4AyIXyECH1cCgB/GgDtpWTgqAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            height: 12px;
            width: 12px
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.8);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
            background-color: rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.8);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:hover,
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.8);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
            background-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.8);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement,
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment,
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement,
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
            height: 12px;
            width: 12px;
            background-position: 50%;
        }

        .container {
            background: orange;
            color: white;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            display: flex; /* this line breaks the scroll bars */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;" class="container">
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 800px">Hello</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem:

[image: problem]

Expected result:

[image: expectation]

Same code on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Mingzilla/0asgu6j1/

Comment: How are they broken? The screenshot is not self explanatory

Comment: The screenshot shows double up and down arrows, and the horizontal scrollbar is missing the dragging part

Comment: The Horizontal bar doesn't have a handle because you are rendering it without any content to actually scroll.

Comment: @Laif Thanks. I have updated the issue so that it's more clear about what's wrong. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Just to make sure: You wrote this code right? did you put the comment on the line that is breaking the code?

Comment: @Laif Yes, I wrote the code and added that line of comment to show that the problem is related to flex layout with scrollbar. It works without problems if .container is not using flex layout. Soon as I turn the .container into display: flex, it no longer works. Unfortunately my system is mostly constructed using flex layout, so I can't get rid of that line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the double arrows, include `:single-button:` in your CSS targets.

Note: The page isn't scrolling left or right because there is no content for it to scroll left and right on. Flexbox will fit all content in the window by flexing it, hence there is no reason for there to be a scrollbar handle. (Changing the inner div to have min-width can also force the horizontal scroll bar to appear)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement {
            background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAABlBMVEXM09b///8OmaLeAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAiSURBVHgBY2BEAxQJMKAJMKAJMKAJMOATgIkQMBTBooZfAH56AO2yINTrAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment {
            background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAABlBMVEXM09b///8OmaLeAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAgSURBVHgBY2BEA+QLMGAIMGAIMGAIMBAUIGQoZU5HAwB+ZgDtGYq3fgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
            background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAABlBMVEXM09b///8OmaLeAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAfSURBVHgBY2BEA7QTYIAChAoYH6EFxkeYwQBj0MelAH3GAO2C9+AaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
            background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAABlBMVEXM09b///8OmaLeAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAgSURBVHgBY2BEAzQVYIAzYHwGGAvOZ4AyIXyECH1cCgB/GgDtpWTgqAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            height: 12px;
            width: 12px
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.8);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
            background-color: rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.8);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:hover,
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.8);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
            background-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.8);
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement,
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment,
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement,
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
            height: 12px;
            width: 12px;
            background-position: 50%;
        }

        .container {
            background: orange;
            color: white;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            display: flex; /* this line turns .container into flex layout */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;" class="container">
    <div style="min-width: 800px; height: 800px">Hello</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks and this solves the problem. Changing the inner div to have min-width: 800px can force the horizontal scrollbar to appear. I'll edit your solution so that it benefits other people if that's ok

Answer (score 0):

### Actually, this is not an issue

> The flexbox specification will not show scrollbar when you are using `align-items: center; justify-content: center` in overflow container. It just center the content.

[image]

```js
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        background: "green",
        overflow: "auto",
      }}
    >
      <Typography
        variant="h6"
        sx={{ background: "cyan", height: 450, width: 450 }}
      >
        The
        <br />
        Amazing
        <br />
        Example
        <br />
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default App;
```

> This behavior can be overwritten by using parent container with `position: relative; overflow: auto` and `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%` child. Check [the link to the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-declarative-scrollview-vzvvht)

[image]

```js
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { ScrollView } from "react-declarative";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView withScrollbar sx={{ height: 300, width: 300 }}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          height: "100%",
          width: "100%,
          background: "green",
        }}
      >
        <Typography
          variant="h6"
          sx={{ background: "cyan", height: 450, width: 450 }}
        >
          The
          <br />
          Amazing
          <br />
          Example
          <br />
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The source code of `<ScrollView />` component is [published in this repo](https://github.com/react-declarative/react-declarative/blob/master/src/components/ScrollView/ScrollView.tsx)